# Automatic classification of outliers

Tags: classification, matlab, outliers, unsupervised-learning

I have the following plot of data:

[image]

and I am trying to separate the main part of the data with the outliers that are far away from the main data (for example the data found at around x=250, around x=300, around x=150 and around x=50 which are clear by eye but I need an automatic way to do it). I cannot fit the data with a particular equation because the data do not look the same in every data set I have, but the outliers that I want to find are always visible by eye like in this plot. I tried to use k-means but the clusters it finds is the left peak and the right peak which is not what I want. Do you have any suggestions on how to separate the main data from the outliers? Maybe an unsupervised learning method? I am not very familiar with machine learning and I am using MATLAB to do this.

Comment: (+1) There's a bit of an art to this sort of thing.  Any information you can share about the typical characteristics of your data, how they vary, how many points might appear in outlying groups, and so on, can be useful in identifying or developing good approaches.

Comment: Usually the outliers are between 1-5% of the overall data and sometimes the second peak on the right is more prominent and sometimes it does not exist at all.

Comment: When you fit an equation, but the data don't really fit it, you need to have (implicitly or explicitly) an error distribution. If you use standard least squares, you implicitly assume normally distributed errors. Using another distribution, e.g. t-distributed errors, can make your fit more robust against outliers, and after you have the fit you can identify outliers by especially large errors.

Comment: What an "outlier" means on this context... Is this a time series?. If the x-axis is time, then i would try to fit a trend first, and then to check the 1-5% suggested as criterium... Though, the data appears to have a linear up & down tendency at x=160, just like in x=60, thus, those "outliers" appears to be actually some nonlinear dynamic...

Comment: It is a time series and I have several of them and not all have the same structure. That is why i am looking of a way to separate the outliers without fitting the data.

Comment: Again, an outlier is *data which do not fit*. Somehow you need to fit something to evaluate how a point is or not outlying. What is your alternative?

Comment: Seconding hypfco, "separate the outliers without fitting the data" doesn't make sense.

Comment: I would be cautious of concluding that data that do not fit are outliers. I think a safer definition (albeit one that makes identifying outliers more difficult) is that outliers are data that come from a different data generating process.

Comment: Here is a very similar question I answered: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152401/data-and-curve-fitting/152631#152631.  Upon further inspection, it seems to be the same question by the same user!